# Optimization Strategies to perform aggregate on 4 Bil records

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

So I have a table of 4.7 billion records on which I want to perform a group by count expression in Postgres using PGadmin4.

Obviously this is gonna take a lot of time and I want to speed up the process as high as possible.

Example query

```
Update TT FROM Target_table TT, (Select col_1, count(col_1) cnt from 
Very_Large_Table
group by col_1) as AA
set tt.qty = AA.cnt
where aa.col1 = tt.col1 and aa.cnt <> tt.qty;
```

I have freshly created/analyzed indexes on the column col_1 still the process takes 2 hours.

Trying parallel hints by adding /+ PARALLEL (very_large_table 6) +/ in select but it seems like a different syntax is required as explained plan still shows 2 workers.

It cannot create partitioning.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am out of ideas now. This is choking the system, and other applications are getting impacted.

Edit: Thanks everyone for all the help but I am looking for ideas to mitigate the problem as I am quite sure anything I write/change directly on PGadmin would not help me here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. That being said, there's not much rdbms magic that can speed up COUNT operations on huge tables. It's possible a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) will help you.

Comment: Also what do you mean by `parallel hints` (a link to the postgresql manuals would be good) and what do you mean by `choking the system`?

Comment: PostgreSQL is not Oracle.  It doesn't have hints, unless you use an extension which adds them.  You should read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html) for the tool you are using.

Comment: If it is "choking the system" on two just parallel workers, why on earth do you want it to use 6 instead?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Parallel Hints : https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/epas/latest/epas_compat_ora_dev_guide/05_optimizer_hints/07_parallelism_hints/

By choking I mean the performance degrades to worse for other queries in other instances.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for the reply. I think currently it is using only 2 workers as it is specified in configs. However if I run something like this "SHOW max_worker_processes;" It reverts me that upto 8 can be used. Correct me if I am wrong. I am really unsure about parallelism in PG

Comment: max_worker_processes is the system-wide limit., not the per-session limit.  You want  max_parallel_workers_per_gather (or not, because again, increasing the beatings is a poor way to improve morale).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there are situations where we don't have any functionality or capabilities of DB to help us solve that problem. In these cases, we have to think of some logical solutions. For example, suppose we need the number of records in a table. If we don't need an exact count, but an approximate count is enough, we can get very high performance by getting this count from information-schema. So, if calculating the count of a table with 4 billion records takes 1-5 minutes, with information-schema we can get it in 1 millisecond.

Now information-schema will not help us in this matter you wrote, because it only gives the count of records of the entire table, grouping prevents us here. But you can use materialized views, if you don't need exactly count of records. Every day on the night you can refreshing this materialized using schedule and use it on day.

Again, after getting to know the issue in depth, knowing the business logic in detail, we can think of different alternative solutions. All I can say is that in all DBs the count command is slow running process on very large tables.

Comment: Hi Thank but the system needs exact counts for all the Col1. The column col1 has approx 1 billion + distinct values.

Comment: @AayushBhatnagar - Are there many records inserting to this table during the day? or has a bulk insert, bulk update?

Comment: Its basically a bulk update where the count coming from this query is set as quantity to the target table. I'll update the query in main post for a better idea

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I guess you need to do queries on your `Target_Table` where each row of your result set shows how many rows from `Very_Large_Table` have the same value of `col_1` as the present row. Your plan seems to be populating your `qty` column with that number.

With respect, your present approach is impractical.

- As you have discovered, it takes too long to populate `qty`.
- The dbms write-locks your tables while you populate `qty`, otherwise insertions, updates and deletions will interfere with the UPDATE query in your question. The locks interfere with other workloads on your dbms.
- Your `qty` values will become stale between times you run your query. Therefore you must treat them as approximate values in your application.

There are other ways to generate the `qty` value you need, when querying. For example, this retrieves your `qty` at the time of your query.

```
SELECT TT.*, COALESCE (q.qty, 0) qty
  FROM Target_Table
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT COUNT(*) qty,
                    col_1
               FROM Very_Large_Table
              GROUP BY col_1
       ) q ON TT.col_1 = q.col_1
 WHERE  something;
```

It seems very likely that you always, or almost always, use a `WHERE something` filter clause when querying. I suspect it's very rare to query the whole table. The presence of a filter, any filter, reduces the number of `col_1` values for which you need `qty`. If the filter is selective enough it reduces that number to a workable value.  This approach has the benefit that `qty` is always up to date.

This index accelerates the query I propose.

```sql
CREATE INDEX col_1 ON Very_Large_Table (col_1);
```

There's another, more elaborate, approach. If you decide to go this direction, give it a try and ask another question if you need help.

- Create a separate table `Col_1_Counts_From_Very_Large_Table` with `col_1` and `qty` columns. Put indexes on `(col_1, qty)` and `(qty, col_1)`.
- Populate it, during some system downtime, with a query like the one in your question.
- Create [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) for insert, update, and delete on your `Very_Large_Table`. Have those triggers update the `qty` values in the appropriate rows in `Col_1_Counts_From_Very_Large_Table`. This keeps your counts table up-to-date whenever somebody changes rows in `Very_Large_Table`.
- Then when you run your query do it like this:

  ```sql
  SELECT TT.*, COALESCE (q.qty, 0) qty
     FROM Target_Table
     LEFT JOIN Col_1_Counts_From_Very_Large_Table q ON TT.col_1 = q.col_1
    WHERE  something;
  ```

This approach will be accurate and fast at query time, at the cost of trigger complexity and small slowdowns on inserts, updates, and deletes to your very large table. It also lets you do things like find `MAX(qty)` or `ORDER BY qty DESC` without dimming the lights in your data center.